# Why did this answer get down- and delete-voted?

Tags: discussion, answers

Here is the answer at hand: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/329219/243450

Comment: "Is there any way to make it better than this?" -- please [don't hijack the answer to ask a new question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/839601) (and before asking that new question properly, ie not in the answer, give a read to [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding))

Comment: @gnat so what if an answer raises another question? By the way, I can delete that line if it is causing such distress.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange is not a traditional forum. We expect that questions contain a question and answers contain answers to that question. If you need to add more information to a question, the post should be edited. If you have a different question, then it shouldn't be asked as an answer, but a new question.

Comment: But stackexchange offers the ability to offer answers in Q/A formats. What's wrong if I ask a question, and I offer the answer? If my answer is the best, I'll accept my own answer. You are wrong.'

Comment: @caveman The read the post twice now. It didn't look like a self answer. It looked like you were simply showing the work that you have already done (which should be included in a question) and then asking about it. Answers should not contain other questions.

Comment: Why didn't anyone simply edit the answer by deleting the 1-line question? Really? You delete an entire correct answer, simply because of a 1 line at the end?

Comment: @caveman You can edit and then flag it for review. It didn't look like it answered the question at all to me, so deletion is the right thing to do so it doesn't serve as a bad example for other people.

Comment: Well, my answer is identical to this other answer that came later http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/329609/243450 except that I used the **counter** variable for clarity --- I guess then you gotta delete this other answer too.

Comment: @caveman No. That question was not flagged for being a question asked in an answer, because it doesn't contain a question.

Comment: If your only problem is that single line of around 4-5 words, then just edit that single line. Why do you delete a whole post with a good answer simply because of a very tiny line?

Comment: @caveman Like I said, it didn't look like an answer at all. It looked like an entirely new question. Based on what I saw, it should have been deleted, so I deleted it in response to flags.

Comment: And your only reason for not noticing that it is an answer, is simply because there was one line of 4-5 words at the end?

Comment: @caveman No. I read the whole thing. It looked like a question and not an answer to the existing question. Since it looked like a question, I deleted it since that's standard practice.

Comment: But why did you see it as an answer? Because of a single 4-5 line at the end? Kindly tell me exactly what is what looks like a question. Because it is an answer, and the only thing that remotely resembles a question is that single 4-5 line at the end.

Comment: @caveman It looked like the text before the question was presenting a problem and not a solution. That, coupled with a question, made it appear to be a question, not an answer.

Comment: How did the text before  looked like presenting a problem, given that it literally said "here is my current **solution**"?

Comment: @caveman A good question should present the work done previously, such as research or a not-good-enough solution. It's quite common to ask people who haven't presented their current work to do so on the question.

Comment: SE also allows Q/A-formatted answers. I.e. you post a question, and then you post your own answer. In this case my answer was literally an answer that was competing to get accepted. It is better to put it as a separate answer, so that if it is the best then it will get accepted. You are confusing other scenarios with this cenario.

Comment: @caveman I'm done explaining my reasoning. Your post was voted on and flagged by other users who thought it was an answer. I handled that flag and agreed. If you can't see why it looks like a question, I really can't help you. We have an expectation that questions are questions and answers are answers and that showing prior work is part of a question and not an answer. That's the end of that.

Comment: It is a Q/A-styled answer. It says **solution** on the 1st line. I literally stated that it is an **answer** in the comments. Your are definitely wrong.

Comment: @caveman: you can discuss this further to death, if you like. But my perception was the same as Thomas': your answer did not look like a real answer to me, it looked like an addendum to your question of the form "I tried this, but I am not pleased with it, so I am looking for something better".

Comment: @DocBrown It was a real answer, but I wasn't sure about it. Nonetheless, I was considering to accept it as an answer if it turns out to be the best. Really, it was an answer, that I wasn't sure about. It is still an answer, and could've been the accepted if it had survived. Please fix your logic. You guys are totally wrong here. I see where you are coming, but you are wrong here, and very wrong. You guys have to change.